# Get the whole range of date in SAS

Tags: date, sas

I know the date in SAS looks like 01Jan2017. What I want is 1 January 2017. Is there function to make it?

Thank,

Andrea

Comment: How about show us your attempts at solving or research into the problem?

Comment: Hi, I just want to show the date in some format. Did not know WORDDATX20. format. Thanks for Mike, pm2r and Bhavika.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code would look like this:

```
data _null_;

    length date1 8. string $40;
    date1=today();
    string = cats( date1 );
    put string=;
    string = cats( put(date1,date10.) );
    put string=;
    string = cats( put(date1,WORDDATX20.) );
    put string=;

run;
```

and the output would be:

```
string=20838
string=19JAN2017
string=19 January 2017
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty vague - it's hard to tell if you just want to display it differently or store it differently.

Display it differently: Just change the format to keep the date as a number in the background (number of days since 01JAN1960) but display it how you would like.

```
data ds1;
   date = '01JAN2017'd;
   format date WORDDATX20.;
run;
```

Store it differently: You can use the put function to create a separate character variable containing the formatted version of your date.

```
data ds2;
   date1 = '01JAN2017'd;
   date2 = put(date1, WORDDATX20.);
run;
```

Answers provided by Bhavika and pm2r should also help you understand what's going on here.